# Why I can't do this substitution?

Tags: probability

Let's say we have two independent  variables, and we need to find $$E[X-Y | X+Y=3]$$
May I know why it doesn't equal to
$$E[2X-3]$$ Since $$X=3-Y$$

Thank you so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The substitution can be done, but the condition $X+Y=3$ does not dissappear, thus
$$E[X-Y \: | \: X+Y=3] = E[2X-3 \: | \: X+Y=3].$$
And usually
$$E[2X-3 \: | \: X+Y=3] \neq E[2X-3].$$

Comment: But, by substituting, we already considered the condition of X+Y=3...... isn't it?

Comment: No. In order to get rid of the conditioning you would usually need stronger assumptions, such as independence. But usually $2X-3$ is not independent of $X+Y$. The answer given by Thomas has a good example which shows why the two expressions are not the same.

Answer (score 5):

Consider if $X$ and $Y$ are two fair die rolls.

Then the only way for $X+Y=3$ is $X=1,Y=2$ or $X=2, Y=1.$ So $E(X-Y\mid X+Y=3)=0.$

But $E[2X-3]=2E[X]-3=4.$

The problem is that the condition $X+Y=3$ changes the probabilities of the values of $X.$

Comment: Yes, the last sentence should be the main takeaway from this question. $X+Y=3$ means you now know something about the value the random variable $X$ has taken, that isn't present in the initial distribution of $X$ and thus cannot be captured in $E[2X-3]$.